# ArcMap 10.6 Choropleth Banding

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, choropleth

We have ArcMap 10.6 at work, and would like create choropleth maps to visualize the  the change in profit (%) that adjusting different business variables would have.

**Note that the actual change in profit probably range from -30% to 40%, but I'd still like to have bands like the ones below that range from -100% to 100%, so that we can easily compare different maps with different scenarios.

For the maps, we'd like to have set 10% profit bands ranging from -100% to 100%.

Something like:

x<-100%
-100%<=x<-90%
-90%<=x<-80%
...
80%<=x<90%
90%<=x<100%
x>100%

How can I accomplish this? I have right-clicked the layer, gone to properties, symbology, picked graduated colors, and picked the variable. When I click classify to create my bands, I can't seem to create the bands that I want.

Also, if I were able to create the bands that I want, is there a way to quickly import them to another map, to avoid rework in getting the bands the way I want them for a new map?